# how to send base64 encoded string of image to server

Tags: java, asp-classic, applet

HI to all In my project I have to send BASE64 string of an image from applet to an asp page which is on IIS Server. When I try it by HttpURLConnection it give Exception IllegalArgumentException: invalid charater in header message

Please help me

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post some code and the exception please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for example[Base64EncoderStream](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/File-Input-Output/BASE64EncoderStreamfromSunMicrosystems.htm)

or example how to setProperty for [HttpURLConnection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) autentifications

```
conn.setRequestProperty("Proxy-Authorization",
"Basic " + new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode((proxyUser 
+ ":" + proxyPassword).getBytes()));
```